# How to replace the autowired bean?

Tags: java, spring, inheritance

I have an external library with the **HumanService.class** and **ActionService.class**

```
@Service("humanService")
public class HumanService {

    private ActionService actionService;

    public HumanService(@Qualifier("actionService") ActionService actionService) {
        this.actionService = actionService;
    }

    public void talk(){
        actionService.talk();
    }
}
```

```
@Service("actionService")
@Slf4j
public class ActionService {

    public void talk(){
        log.info("Hi");
    }

}
```

On the other hand, I have a Spring Boot Project that include the library. And I am trying to replace the bean **actionService** with the new class **ActionBService.class** for overriding the **talk()**.

```
@Service("actionService")
@Slf4j
public class ActionBService extends ActionService{

    @Override
    public void talk() {
        log.info("Hello Action B");
    }
}
```

However, this approach will hit the bean name ConflictingBeanDefinitionException. And I tried **@Primary**, it is still not work. How do I replace the existing bean easily for customising the function?

Comment: step one: make those qualifiers unique. if you don't, there is no point at using them in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Add the below property in application.properties to override the bean definition.

```
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```